# How can I disable a submit button in an HTML form?

Tags: html, forms, submit-button

I have a form where users can contact me but it is currently broken. I was wondering if there is a way to temporarily disable the submit button, but still show it on the screen. How do I achieve this?

```
<form method="post" action="#">
    <div class="row 50%">
        <div class="6u"><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" /></div>
        <div class="6u"><input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" /></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row 50%">
        <div class="12u"><textarea name="message" placeholder="Message" rows="6"></textarea></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="12u">
            <ul class="actions">
                <li><input type="submit" value="Send Message" /></li>
                    <li><input type="Reset" value="Clear" /></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: `<input type="submit" value="Send Message" disabled>`

Comment: @APAD1 That simple? I couldn't find the answer on google anywhere...

Comment: Yep, it is [that simple](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_disabled.asp)

Comment: You can't style disabled button sing css.

Comment: @user3760661 yes you can. `input:disabled {}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<input type="submit" value="Send Message" disabled>
```

Thanks APAD1

Comment: small note, for crossbrowser (fallback) support use `<input type="submit" value="Send Message" disabled="disabled">`